# Use stat_summary for nested functions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data taken over the course of a day, that looks like so:

```r
data <- data.frame(
  error = rnorm(45),
  tod = rep(seq(500, 1900, 100))
)
```

Where `tod` is the time of day. I plot using `ggplot` to make a nice error ribbon:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(tod, error)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(df$hour, 15))
```

Here's the tricky question: I'd like to now swap the grid and x axis, from the continuous time one, to a discrete "time of day" one, that has 5 labelled ticks instead of the current 15 (i.e. morning, noon, afternoon, evening, night). The actual ribbon plot should stay the same, which is why changing the data in `tod` wouldn't work.

I did try adding `scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 5, labels = c(...))` but i get and error saying that my breaks and labels are of different length. The minimal number of breaks R would plot is 6 in this case, but even with `n.breaks = 6` and 6 labels it wouldn't budge.

Edit:
I now used:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(tod, error)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 9, limits = c(500, 1900) ,labels = c('', 'sunrise', 'morning', '', 'midday', '', 'afternoon', 'evening', ''))
```

I did try doing it with 5 before. However, with 5 breaks, `ggplot` insists on *actually* plotting 9, and hiding the first and last one. When choosing 9, `ggplot` plots 17. I just don't understand what causes this and it's very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You should just keep using `breaks` instead of `n.breaks` Iguess.
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html

> n.breaks
> An integer guiding the number of major breaks. The algorithm may choose a slightly different number to ensure nice break labels. Will only have an effect if breaks =
> waiver(). Use NULL to use the default number of breaks given by the transformation.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up also using `minor_breaks = 0` and then naming the first and last ticks as empty and it does the job, though I can't call it optimal.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny As suggested by Trung Anh Pham, this works for me `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(600,1900,300), labels = c('sunrise', 'morning', 'midday', 'afternoon', 'evening'))`